# Is possible to call a non-payable function of smart contract and send Ether to contract at same time?

Tags: web3js, tokens, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets

I deployed and verified a smart contract without declared a function as payable. Now I need to send ether at same time a non-payable function is called.

Any posibility? I don't want my DApp to pay gas twice

Comment: I suggest deploying again while you presumably have few users using the contract. The alternative of writing a contract that sends ether and calls a function, doesn't seem worth it. Also, it is best to avoid SELFDESTRUCT as it may be removed: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4758

Comment: @eth The contract has already been verified. It annoys me to have two contracts with the same name on Etherscan. It is confusing for users because Etherscan dont let me to remove the old one from the search.

Comment: Other considerations. 1. You probably should have your own UI and anyone searching on Etherscan should compare the address against your UI. 2. You also can't prevent anyone from deploying a contract with same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new smart contract and pass the smart contract address that you want to send ether as an owner contract inside the newly deployed contract. You can call self.destruct on your new contract which would transfer all the money to your already deployed contract.

Here is more on that: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-hack-smart-contracts-self-destruct-and-solidity

Comment: But selfdestruct() destroy the new contract? I need to use it a lot of times.
Maybe I can create a new contract thats call the current contract function   and make the ether transfer to my address ...

Comment: I tried it. No selfdestruct is needed because I can do a transfer to a wallet address. My problem is that the original contract function control the msg.sender. It require the NFT owner, therefore I can´t call it from the new contract because has a different sender. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

the first thing does your contract have a fallback function, if it has you can deploy a new contract and use a call to send ether to it

a fallback function will only be triggered if

1. If a function identifier doesn't match any of the available functions in a smart contract
2. If there was no data supplied along with the function call.

example: contract_addr.call{value: amt}("func_name("param_type")", param);

func_name = function name
value = amount of ether you want to send
contract_addr = address of the contract you want to send ether to
param_type = the parameter type may be unit,address,string
param = parameter to pass into the function

if you don't, you will have to create a new contract with a self-destruct function contract send ether to your new contract(make sure you put a withdraw function in the new contract), pass in the address of the contract you want to send ether to into the selfdestruct function and call it

Comment: I made it.  No selfdestruct is needed because I can do a transfer to a wallet address. 
My problem is that the original contract function control the msg.sender. It require the NFT owner, therefore I can´t call it from the new contract because has a different sender